# Java How do I check for update?

Tags: java, ftp, project

I got a project and I would like that it updates when I upload a new version to a server.

My projects are classic Java projects if that helps.

How do I do that?

How do I detect a change of a file in a server without any additional files (no txt and such) ->(eg: md5 (no idea if possible) to compare with a file on local disk)

FTP: Hello.zip (md5 = 123)
Local: Hello.zip (md5 = 122)

-> IN PROGRAM: if(FTP_Hello.zip_MD5 != Local_Hello.zip_MD5){ Download(); }

Comment: If it's a web application, maybe use JSP, since it's dynamic. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it -

You can put a periodic check in your application to read http://yourserver.com/yourapp_version.xml

and store relevant information (e.g. current version, and download path for jar/war/ear etc.) in this xml file, put logic in your app to compare its own version to the version written in this file, and if it determines that update is available then download the new jar/war/ear and install according to your environment.

Hope the idea helps.